# How many spell slots does a character get?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

How many spell slots does a character get, and how do you calculate that if there's a calculation involved? I've been looking everywhere for this, but can't find it.

I started playing just about a month ago and I've had to make about 2 character sheets for my friends already (Human Fighter and a Wood-Elf Ranger) and now I'm making myself a Cleric of Life but can't figure out how many spell slots I have.

Comment: Hi Scorpon, and welcome to the site! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. I've given your question a trim to make it more to the point and to lead with the question. Also, since your user card is attached to every question or answer you create, we don't sign posts here - they're already signed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Spell Slots

To figure out how many spell slots, simply go to the class table.
 For the cleric: the table is found at the top of pg.57 *PHB*. It shows that a 1st level cleric has 2 1st level spell slots.

Each class has a similar table that is usually found  in the first few pages of a particular class section.

#### Spell Casting

To get more insight into a particular class spellcasting abilities read the section on *Spellcasting* for that class.
 For instance the *Spellcasting* section(pg.58) of the cleric states that the cleric can prepare as many spells as his Lvl + WIS mod.